# Not able to set Chrome local storage in extension (undefined)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Not able to set Chrome local storage in extension (undefined)

I have a Chrome extension I'm trying to read and write to local storage with like this:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({lty_username: username}, function(){
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
    } 
    else {
        console.log("Username saved: " + username);
    }
});

chrome.storage.local.get(["lty_username"]).then((result) => {
    alert("Value currently is " + result.key);
});
```

But when I read the same key/value set to local storage, it is always undefined. There are no errors in the console.

Here's is my manifest.json file:

```
{
    "name": "name",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "description",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "author": "author",
    "action":{
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_title": "title"
    },
    "host_permissions": [
    "*://*.facebook.com/",
    "*://*.twitter.com/",
    "*://*.linkedin.com/",
    "*://*.nextdoor.com/",
    "*://*.instagram.com/",
    "*://*.reddit.com/",
    "*://*.quora.com/"
    ],
    "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "storage"
    ]
}
```

I can't figure out why values are not being set in local storage. Anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugging tool inside the chrome browser? If you place some breakpoints you can check if A) the code is even reached. B) the code get skipped over. Since you state nothing appears in the console this might be caused by the code not even reaching the set statement

Comment: Also make sure your console has the option `Selected context only` disabled

Comment: AFAIK, extensions have [their specific storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/).

Comment: @Philippe I am using chrome.storage

Comment: @Roe It is reaching the code, I can see "Username saved: ...." in the console.

Comment: Oo sorry, bad review for my side :/ All my apologizes.

Comment: @us1LfMz try [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storage-area-explorer/ocfjjjjhkpapocigimmppepjgfdecjkb) this should give you some insight into the stored data from chrome.storage

Comment: @us1LfMz - Is this EXACTLY the same code you're running on your computer, or did you change something before pasting it into your question? I'm asking because many people make "minor" changes to their code before posting it on SO, and these changes introduce major bugs.

Comment: @ThomasMueller yes, exactly the same code, except manifest.json name, author and description.

Comment: @us1LfMz - 1) `result.key` should be `result.lty_username` - 2) If you're only getting a single key from storage, you can use a string instead of an array of strings `chrome.storage.local.get("lty_username")`